# IO Completion Ports and OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl

I have some legacy code that uses OpenSSL for communication. Just like any other session it does a handshake using the SSL functions and then encrypted communication over TCP. We recently changed our code to use IO completion ports. The way it works is contrary to that of OpenSSL. Basically, I'm having a hard time migrating our secure communication code from full OpenSSL usage to IOCP sockets and OpenSSL encryption.

Does anyone have/anyone know of any references that might help me with such a task? 
How would TLS handshaking work over IOCP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use OpenSSL for encryption, but do your own socket IO, what you basically do is create a memory BIO, that you read and write socket data into as that becomes available, and attach that to the SSL context.

Each time you do a SSL_write call, you follow up with a call to the memory BIO to see if it has data in its read buffer, read that out and send it.
Conversely, when data arrives on the socket via your io completion port mechanism, you write it to the BIO and call SSL_read to read the data out. SSL_read might return an error code indicating its in a handshake, which usually means its generated more data to write - which you handle by reading the memory BIO again.

---

To create my SSL session, I do this:

```
// This creates a SSL session, and an in, and an out, memory bio and
// attaches them to the ssl session.
SSL* conn = SSL_new(ctx);
BIO* bioIn = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO* bioOut = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
SSL_set_bio(conn,bioIn,bioOut);
// This tells the ssl session to start the negotiation.
SSL_set_connect_state(conn);
```

As I receive data from the network layer:

```
// buf contains len bytes read from the socket.
BIO_write(bioIn,buf,len);
SendPendingHandshakeData();
TryResendBufferedData(); // see below
int cbPlainText;
while( cbPlainText = SSL_read(ssl,&plaintext,sizeof(plaintext)) >0)
{
  // Send the decoded data to the application
  ProcessPlaintext(plaintext,cbPlaintext);
}
```

As I receive data from the application to send - you need to be prepared for SSL_write to fail because a handshake is in progress, in which case you buffer the data, and try and send it again in the future after receiving some data.

```
if( SSL_write(conn,buf,len) < 0)
{
  StoreDataForSendingLater(buf,len);
}
SendPendingHandshakeData();
```

And SendPendingHandshakeData sends any data (handshake or ciphertext) that SSL needs to send.

```
while(cbPending = BIO_ctrl_pending(bioOut))
{
  int len = BIO_read(bioOut,buf,sizeof(buf));
  SendDataViaSocket(buf,len); // you fill this in here.
}
```

Thats the process in a nutshell. The code samples arn't complete as I had to extract them from a much larger library, but I believe they are sufficient to get one started with this use of SSL. In real code, when SSL_read/write / BIO_read/write fail, its probably better to call SSL_get_error and decide what to do based on the result: SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ is the important one and means that you could not SSL_write any more data, as it needs you to read and send the pending data in the bioOut BIO first.

Comment: This is an excellent example. In a case where I'm the server, would I just substitute the SSL_set_connect_state() call for the SSL_set_accept_state() call?

Comment: I have only worked with client side sockets and OpenSSL, but from my understanding of the documentation it should be that simple.

Comment: Alright. Also, Why is it prudent to call SendPendingHandshakeData() everywhere? I'm assuming that handshaking only happens once, at the beginning of the session. Or does it happen every time a packet is sent out?

Comment: The ssl handshake can in theory be re-triggered at any time if the other side of the connection has a policy requiring that. Plus, writing the code like that makes it nicely stateless so it doesn't need to go from a 'negotiating' to a 'connected' state.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html)

Comment: Yes, there's some examples in the link I posted.

Comment: Even if it doesn't quite answer the question, boost::asio has enough awesomeness inside it to deserve a +1.